# Can't create a new query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

For the past month I have been working on my project, 
but since a couple days now I am unable to create a new query when right clicking my database. This only occurs on one out of three pc's I work on.

This is what it looks like when right clicking my table directory:

[image: Database problem]

It normally includes the options "Add table" and "New query".

I haven't had this problem before and am currently using SQL Server 2014 Express (same as on the two other pc's)

Does anyone have a solution by any chance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check your permissions.

Comment: You can also check for enough space on your database or make sure your database is not read only.

Comment: @SikandarAmla How do i check these? Since i can still use it as normal on my other pc's, i presume the database will not be read-only.

Comment: Yes, in that case it is not. Use the same user id as you are using on the other computer.

Comment: @SikandarAmla Sorry for asking, but i don't see where and how.

Comment: Login details will appear when you will start Management Studio. Either it will be Windows Authentication or SQL Server Authentication.